# "In the (near) future" or "for the (near) future"

Tags: prepositions, idiomatic-language, prepositional-phrases

I am wondering what is the difference between the following two sentences:

1. The aforementioned signs point to a water shortage in the near future.
2. The aforementioned signs point to a water shortage for the near future

I guess the correctness or wrongness of prepositional phrase  mainly depends on what it modifies. In fact, I think  both of "Shortage for the future" and "Shortage in the future" are idiomatic phrases. However, I am not sure about it. Hence, my question. Thank you!

Comment: I think you are confusing it with _for the foreseeable future_ (it's happening now and will continue). _In the near future_ means that it isn't happening yet, but soon will.

Comment: The "default" preposition here is ***in***, which makes your second version at least *slightly* "marked". If I knew it had come from a competent native speaker, I would assume the second version was intended to convey *in the near future **for the short-term*** (i.e. we shouldn't assume the impending water shortage will last indefinitely, which would otherwise be the *default* implication). But if it came from a non-native speaker I'd just assume they didn't make "the best" choice of preposition for the context.

Comment: ...the reason for that distinction is if something's in store ***for*** someone / something, it's usually ***specifically*** for that person or thing (not necessarily for *other* people / things). So something identified  as being ***for** the **near** future* carries at least *some* implication of ***not** for the **far** future*.